# Javascript Cleaning up an array during creation

Tags: javascript, arrays

Edit**  After reading some replies, I am looking to not include single characters/code/special characters in the initial creation of the words array.

Using the code from [THIS LINK](http://iamnotagoodartist.com/web/quick-and-dirty-word-frequency-analysis-with-javascript/) and running it from the console while on any website, we get an array with thousands of words which have already been sorted in the desired order and it is called "words".

I want to grab the top 25 which I can do with:

```
cleanArray = words.slice(0, 25);
console.log(cleanArray);
```

I would like to iterate through the words array, removing any element that is only a single character in length, OR contains any special characters / code tags etc

Not sure if its better to do that after words array is built or while building the words array.

Comment: That depends how the array is built. Can you show how that is done?

Comment: It also depends on if you need exactly 25 words in the end, or if it's OK for you to grab 25 and then find out that 20 of them will have to be filtered out. It's not just a question of "better".

Comment: Do you need exactly 25 in the array when you're done filtering? What if the first 10 "words" are thrown out, is that okay? If it's the former, I'd suggest just iterating through the `words` array and add acceptable words to your `cleanArray` as you go then break out of the loop when you have enough of them collected.

Comment: `clean=words.filter(/./.test, /\w{2,}/).filter(/./.test, /^[\s\w]+$/)`

Comment: @MikeC Looking to not include single characters/code/special characters in the initial creation of the words array. then the code I have above will be fine for returning the top 25 -- seems better than having to re-filter after

Comment: @forgivenson the example is provided in the link

Comment: @ZiNG Oh, so you're just asking which is better: while generating `words` or filtering from `words`? Well, that's all up to opinion but I'm sure a lot of people would agree with me in saying that it'd be better to do the filtering as you generate the array in the first place. Any other method requires you to iterate through at least a subset of the array *again* in order to filter out the results. If you just filter as you populate then you save yourself some cycles. Otherwise, I'd suggest what I said before; go through the minimum number of items required in `words` and generate a new array.

Comment: @MikeC Asking which is better, but also how to achieve it during the initial generation of the array.  im trying to wrap my head around how that works in that given code.

Comment: @ZiNG How are you generating `words`? That will determine how to exclude certain values as you generate others.

Comment: @MikeC It is available from the link in the initial post -- run it from the console while on any page

Comment: @ZiNG Oh. Well... Just modify the part that ignores certain words to also ignore your special cases... [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1bt970ko/)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the array is built, it would be better to simply never add them in the first place because they'll you'll need to remove them later, wasting two actions.
However, there are many situations where skipping entries during creation time aren't an option, string `split`ing being one of them.

As a rule of thumb, never do more work than necessary, and if you're not sure, benchmark.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense that it would be better to do intially.  how would you exclude those things during initial array creation with the given code?

Comment: Modify this line: `if (!ignore[sWord]) {` into something like `if (!ignore[sWord] && checkWordForValidity(sWord)) {`